# Distribution list with external email sent from outside

Tags: email, exchange-2010, email-server, distribution-lists

I have Exchange Server 2010 in my environment and I have the following problem with Distribution Lists.

I have created one Distribution List which includes email addresses from our company and external email addresses.

When I send from inside all works fine.

But when I send from outside the email received from inside users(email addresses of my domain) but never received from outside email addresses.

How can resolve this issue?

---

i have change this setting when create the group.But my problem isn't that users from outside can't send to distribution list.
The problem is that in my distribution list i have email addresses from my company (@domain.com) and external email addresses (@gmail.com,@yahoo.com).

When a user from inside send to the Distribution List all works fine.
When a user from outside send to the Distribution List, users from my company(@domain.com) which include in the Distribution List receive the email but user with external email addresses(@gmail.com,@yahoo.com) didn't receive the email.

Answer (score 5):

This is an easy fix.

Think about the reason for this default. Many organizations do NOT want their internal email distribution groups to be presented to the world. Imagine an outside person sending an email to ***everyone@pacific-cucumber.com***. But other times, there are a few addresses that *do* need the ability to receive email from the outside.

Common examples are: info@xyz.com or sales@abc.com - That's where the following settings come in handy:

Navigate to the distribution group's properties under `Recipient Configuration` in the Exchange Management Console...

Open `Mail Flow Settings` -> `Message Delivery Restrictions`.

**Uncheck** "Require that all senders are authenticated" - Save and exit.

[image]